# Getting maximum row in group?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the maximum ID in each group of UIDs.

```
ID   UID 
23    1  
24    1  
25    2  
26    2
```

Would give:

```
ID   UID 
24    1  
26    2
```

How do I get the maximum row in each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)-operator and group by `UID`.

```
SELECT MAX(t.ID), t.UID
FROM yourtable AS t
GROUP BY t.UID;
```