# Getting the max bid price for each auction in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Group getting maximum row in group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876910/group-getting-maximum-row-in-group)

So I have a table that holds bids
Having auction_id and bid_price and bidder_id
I need to get a result set that would contain the highest bid for EACH auction.
is there a way where i can get a max value for each auction_id?
Thanks

EDIT

SELECT MAX(bid_price), auction_id,bidder_username
From bids
GROUP BY auction_id;

This is what I'm doing right now, but it is not returning the correct bidder_username.

MAX(bid_price)  Auction id

71.32           10      customer
99.00           11      customer

but in the database the 1 who bid 71.32 is not that user

auction id    bidder_user_name   bid_time               bid_price

10     testing          1991-11-26 12:12:12 71.32

Comment: Review the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). This is a rudimentary `MAX(bid_price)` `GROUP BY auction_id`.

Comment: @Jocelyn I find it shocking that I could not locate another max() aggregate question as clear as the one you linked, as weak as that one is.

Answer (score 0):

With your query:

```
SELECT MAX(bid_price), auction_id,bidder_username From bids GROUP BY auction_id;
```

you're only grouping by auction_id, so you'll get the `MAX` bid_price across all records.

What you want to do is group by auction *and* user, e.g:

```
SELECT auction_id, bidder_username, MAX(bid_price) as max_price
from bids
GROUP BY auction_id, bidder_username;
```

I think the query also becomes more legible if the GROUP BY items are clearly shown in the SELECT and the functions are at the end, but that may just be a personal preference.